# Playframework with thread-pool for background job

Tags: playframework, threadpool, amqp

In my playframework application (I'm very new to play) I want to be able to handle events rising from the domain model that will be published to an AMQP exchange. I think this could be a multi-threaded background event handler that handles the events and handles the connections to the message broker. I have had had a look at the Jobs class but can't see a way to specify any kind of thread pool. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Best,

Jon

Answer (score 5):

ThreadPool is managed by Play, not by app. What you need to do is just create a job class, and schedule it to run:

```
@On("cron.handleAMQP")
public class MyAMQPHandler extends play.jobs.Job{
   public void doJob() {
      // your logic to handle AMQP message comes here
   }
}
```

Where "cron.handleAMQP" could be one item in your application.conf:

```
cron.handleAMQP=0 0 12 * * ?
```

Comment: Never realised you could take the cron settings from the configh: **cron.** great tip, tx

Comment: @green Thanks for that. I've now seen the play.jobs.pool property in application.conf. I'm now doing new EventHandler(Event).now() to immediately get one of the threads to process the event.

Comment: @jdh, yes you can do that. I suggest keep the play's default configuration for pool setting. By default it will be number-of-cpu-cores + 1 in prod mode and 1 in dev mode